# Annotating Pandas Bar Chart with Images

Tags: python, pandas, image, matplotlib, png

I want to annotate a horizontal bar chart I created with Pandas with '⭑' characters.  The number of stars per bar is determined by a rating system that ranges from zero to five stars and contains half-star ratings.  My issue is that there is no 1/2 star text character, so I have to use images which contain half-stars to properly annotate the bars.

Here is the code to create a sample from the DataFrame I am working from:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(7), 
                  data={'Scores': [79.0, 79.5, 81.8, 76.1, 72.8, 87.6, 79.3]})
df['Stars'] = df['Scores'].apply(real_stars)
```

And here is the function that is determining the star ratings:

```
def real_stars(x):
    if x >=88:
        return ('★★★★★')
    elif x >=83:
        return ('★★★★¹/₂')
    elif x >=79:
        return ('★★★★')
    elif x >=75:
        return ('★★★¹/₂')
    elif x >=71:
        return ('★★★')
    elif x >=67:
        return ('★★¹/₂')
    elif x >=63:
        return ('★★')
    elif x >=59:
        return ('★¹/₂')
    elif x >=55:
        return ('★')
    elif x >=50:
        return ('¹/₂★')
    else:
        return None
```

And this is the code I use to plot the bar chart and annotate the right side of each bar with a star rating:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7.5,5))
ax = plt.subplot()
plt.box(on=None) 

df.plot.barh(ax=ax, width=.75, legend=False)

for i, p in zip(df['Stars'], ax.patches):
    width, height = p.get_width(), p.get_height()
    x, y = p.get_xy() 
    ax.annotate(i, (p.get_x()+1*width, p.get_y()+.45*height), fontsize=25, 
                fontweight='bold', color='white', ha='right', va='center')
```

I would like to annotate the bars the exact same way, but instead of  expressing a half star rating as '1/2', I would instead like to include an image of a half star.  I think the first step would be to incorporate the images in the real_stars function, display the images in the df['Stars'] column and then use the column for annotation.

Examples of images I would like to use:

[.5 star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03zm2.png)
[1 star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbUwx.png)

Comment: Have you seen this demo? https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/demo_annotation_box.html

Answer (score 0):

Half star characters were added into unicode version 11, for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as mfm

font_path = '<PATH>/Symbola.ttf'
prop = mfm.FontProperties(fname=font_path) # find this font

# Some examples of stars
uni_char = u"\u2605\U0001F7CA\u2BE8\u2BEA"
plt.annotate(uni_char, (0.5, 0.5), fontproperties=prop, fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Please see [this](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2be8/index.htm), and note that you have to use fonts that support the newer standard in this [list](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2be8/fontsupport.htm).  The example above uses Symbola

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I downloaded the Symbola font and used the matplotlib.font_manager to create a font-path but I cannot get the half star to display properly in my jupyter notebook or when I export to excel.  It shows us just as a square.   Do you have any further suggestions for how I can get this to work?   Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To annotate bars with shapes one may use an `AnchoredOffsetbox`, which contains a `DrawingArea`. The shapes inside the `DrawingArea` are defined in display space, relative to the Offsetbox.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.markers
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredOffsetbox, DrawingArea

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class AnchoredDrawingArea(AnchoredOffsetbox):
    def __init__(self, width, height, xdescent, ydescent,
                 loc, pad=0.4, borderpad=0.5, **kwargs):
        self.da = DrawingArea(width, height, xdescent, ydescent)
        super().__init__(loc, pad=pad, borderpad=borderpad,
                         child=self.da, **kwargs)

def get_star(pos=0, size=10, half=False, **kwargs):
    marker = matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle("*")
    p = marker.get_path()
    v = np.round(list(p.vertices[:]), 4)
    c = np.array(list(p.codes[:]))

    v *= size
    v[:,0] += pos*2*size

    if half:
        v = np.delete(v, np.s_[6:-1],0)
        c = np.delete(c, np.s_[6:-1],0)
    return PathPatch(Path(v, c), **kwargs)

def draw_star(x,y,s, ax, size=10, **kwargs):
    # https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/anchored_artists.html
    ada = AnchoredDrawingArea(np.ceil(s)*2*size-size, size, size/2, size/2, loc="lower center", 
                              bbox_to_anchor=(x,y,0,0), bbox_transform=ax.transData,
                              frameon=False)

    for i in range(int(s)):
        star = get_star(i, size=size, **kwargs)
        ada.da.add_artist(star)
    h = s - int(s)
    if h > 0:
        star = get_star(int(s), size=size, half=True, **kwargs)
        ada.da.add_artist(star)
    return ada

def draw_stars(x, y, s, ax=None, size=10, **kwargs):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    for xi,yi,si in zip(x,y,s):
        ada = draw_star(xi,yi,si, ax=ax, size=size, **kwargs)
        ax.add_artist(ada)


x = np.arange(6)
y = np.array([4,5,3,4,2,4])
stars = np.array([4, 2.5, 1, 3.5, 4.5, 2])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(x,y)

draw_stars(x,y,stars, ax=ax, size=5, linewidth=0.72,
           facecolor="crimson", edgecolor="darkred")

ax.margins(y=0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image]